Is deleting files from HDFS using the trash a "light" I/O process?
I've been tasked with finding + deleting numerous files (I'd say tens of thousands of them) within our HDFS storage. This delete operation will use the Trash (i.e. no -skipTrash).
I'm new to Hadoop / HDFS, but I've been able to read internal documentation / procedures / scripts, and most of them run operations on HDFS using various parallelization techniques.

is it safe to infer from this answer that deleting files from HDFS actually moves them to the trash, which in turn only moves metadata but not the data itself ?
if so, is it true to say this uses few disk I/O per deleted file and that it's rather fast ? ("fast" meaning way faster than reading + writing each file entirely from its source directory to the trash, implying the copy of GB of data)
would running batches of files to delete in parallel actually increase performance ? Or isn't it worth the added complexity ?

